# ANDing search keywords for elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

How can we configure elastic search so that it only returns results which matches all the words in the search query. The documents indexed have data having multiple fields and so the words of search query may match different fields of data but all the words must get matched in the result ?

Comment: i think panidiyan Cool  is correct as query String query fits best for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can [query string query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) feature to search for results

sample search query

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "(content:this OR name:this) AND (content:that OR name:that)"
        }
    }
}
```

In this query **content** and **name** is the field name, **this** is the search criteria

you can build search query similar to that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for a `multi_match` query together with `and` operator. This is the link to docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html and it seems that `cross_fields`is query type you're looking for. I'd read more on that page, but this is probably what you are looking for:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":      "Will Smith",
      "type":       "cross_fields",
      "fields":     [ "first_name", "last_name" ],
      "operator":   "and"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if a field has space seperated texts then it doesn't work that well ,also the anding result are better only when no of fields matched is atmax 3 whenever i pass a query string which requires matching from four or more fields result degrades instead of improving

Comment: @sumit then a better approach would be to create a computed field where data you want to search against is copied from other fields. Check `copy_to` out.